# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have error `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'`

My code :

```
case Operation.Angle:
    Quaternion quaternion1 = new Quaternion(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
    Quaternion quaternion2 = new Quaternion(values2[0], values2[1], values2[2], values2[3]);
    quaternion = Quaternion.Angle(quaternion1, quaternion2);
    break;
```

Even using the basic quaternions instead of a float I get the same error.

Documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html

Comment: `Quaternion.Angle` returns a `float`.  I have a feeling the variable `quaternion` is not a float.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the bigger picture?

Comment: @derHugo Indeed I just misread the documentation, it happens to me sometimes to read hundreds of times without understanding, I really have to learn to take breaks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hijinxbassist it reflects on my memory, that's working too much.

Thanks again.

Returns the angle in degrees between two rotations a and b.

Example: Think of two GameObjects (A and B) moving around a third GameObject (C). Lines from C to A and C to B create a triangle which can change over time. The angle between CA and CB is the value Quaternion.Angle provides.

IS RETURN A FLOAT.

Documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html